2019: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
  -- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Reverse Engineering over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          7
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            19        210
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                6         35
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         10         83
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                2        122
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue               163        750
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue              148        823
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Questions reopened                                2          0
Questions protected                               0          5
Questions migrated                                1          0
Questions flagged⁵                                0         93
Questions closed                                178         63
Question flags handled⁵                          83         10
Posts undeleted                                   1         20
Posts locked                                      0          3
Posts deleted⁶                                  134        731
Posts bumped                                      0        350
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                 74        186
Comments deleted⁷                               158        459
Comment flags handled                            95        165
Answers flagged                                   4        219
Answer flags handled                            205         18
All comments on a post moved to chat              2          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Reverse Engineering without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).   
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: 2018: a year in moderation...
You can also check out this report on other sites
Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites

Wishing you all a happy new year...
